# Where should I add code to run side-effects attached to Redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, electron

I'm building a desktop app using Electron, React, and Redux.

One of the key components of this desktop app is going to be tying certain components of my redux state to physical files on the drive.  The website is the 'master' copy of whether certain data is accessible to the user.  The app downloads a list of files it should have access to, and then tracks which files have already been downloaded.  A typical workflow would be to load the list, then hit 'download', and when the item is downloaded, use it in the app.

When I update the local redux list of items, I need to also manage the state of those files.  When a record is removed from the redux store, I need to delete the associated physical files.

This puts me in a weird space.  It feels really, really odd to write a reducer that makes changes to the local file structure.  It's even worse because I'm using electron-redux to keep multiple processes in sync -- I'm running a complete redux stack in both the main process and my renderer window(s), with electron-redux to keep them in a shared state.

The more I look at this, the more it feels like the reducer is completely the wrong place to do this.  The flip side is that this code definitely needs to happen based on *state*, which makes redux the exact right place to do it.  Not sure what the right solution here is -- I have contradicting design principles in play, and I'm not sure how to resolve that.

Edit:

Part of the difficulty here is that the reducer isn't doing a simple replacement of state.  In this case, the reducer is doing a pretty complicated algorithm:

Current State:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    serverState: 'red',
    localState: 'file'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    serverState: 'green',
    localState: 'file-processed'
  }
]
```

The server might send (and therefore my action payload contains):

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    serverState: 'purple',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    serverState: 'blue',
  }
]
```

As a result, I need to merge data, so my state *becomes*:

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    serverState: 'purple',
    localState: 'file-processed'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    serverState: 'blue',
    localState: 'no-file'
  }
]
```

Note that Item #2's localState didn't change, but the serverState items were overwritten.  Item #1's local files would need to be removed from the file system, user no longer has permissions for them.

Answer (score 1):

The reducer is not the right place for side-effects other than changing the store.

There are libraries made for handling side-effects in relation to redux. For example, there's redux-saga: https://redux-saga.js.org/

Redux-saga is a redux middleware, and sagas are triggered by the same actions that you would use to update the redux store.

Comment: So I may be missing an important detail here.  I need access to both the existing state, and the incoming, new state.  If I currently have Foo IDs [1, 2], and the incoming is [2, 3], I need to clean up 1, add 3.

Comment: To get the current state in a saga, use redux-saga’s select(), you know what changes are being made to the state because those changes are in the payload of the action that provoked this saga to run. Do your side-effects and then put() an action your reducer will catch to update the state accordingly.

Comment: I think I see the issue here.  This isn't a case of state = newState.  The reducer actually generates the new state -- it's supposed to pull in data, crunch it, and output the new state.  See original question for more details.